# How can I display the image from the related entry for each entry in craft CMS and twig?

Tags: twig, octobercms, craftcms

I have a a list of entries.
Each entry has a related person.
Each related person has an avatar.

On my index page I am looping over the entries and creating a `<div>` with the persons details. Eg

```
{% set person = entry.relatedPerson[0] ?? null %}

<p>{{person.firstName}} {{person.lastName}} </p>
```

I need to access the picture related to the person.

Have tried this which displays a list of every asset that is an image in its own div.

```
{% set person = entry.relatedPerson[0] ?? null %} 
{% for image in craft.assets.kind('image') %}
    <li>
          <img src="{{ image.getUrl }}" alt="{{ image.title }}">
    </li>
{% endfor %}
```

I have also tried this which shows nothing

```
{% set person = entry.relatedPerson[0] ?? null %}
{% for image in person.assets.kind('image') %}
    <li>
        <img src="{{ image.getUrl }}" alt="{{ image.title }}">
    </li>
{% endfor %}
```

How can I add the relatedPerson image to each card?
Also it would be great if you could explain as I'm not understanding templating. The docs aren't sufficient for me

Comment: See [here](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/2837/fetch-image-url-from-entry-cms). Replace `featureImage` with the field name you gave your avatar I assume

Comment: This hasn't been working for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you missed the parenthesis after getUrl "()" in your code to fetch the image. The getUrl is a method.

```
{% set person = entry.relatedPerson[0] ?? null %} 
{% for image in craft.assets.kind('image') %}
    <li>
          <img src="{{ image.getUrl() }}" alt="{{ image.title }}">
    </li>
{% endfor %}
```

Use the getUrl as I used in the above code.
I hope it will work for you.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the image, Try the below code:

```
{% for block in entry.relatedPerson.all() %}    
    {% set image= block.<image-handle>.one() %}
    <li>
      <img src="{{ siteUrl }}<image-path>/{{ image.filename}}" alt="{{ image.filename }}">
    </li>
{% endfor %}
```